# PDO Prepared statement Inside a class

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to use an update method inside my Database class where I could be able to update a record. I am trying to make sure that I could use the method in another instance where i dont have to repeat writing the same statement. Here is my code:

```
<?php 
require 'init.php';
class Database {
    private $conn;

    public function __construct() {
        try {
            $this->conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=school', DB_USER, DB_PASS);
            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function update($table, $key, $value, $id) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE $table SET $key = $value WHERE id = :id");
        return $stmt->execute(array($key => $value, 'id' => $id));
    }
}
$database = new Database();
```

My problem is i get some errors when i try to instantiate the class `$result = $database->update('admin', 'username', 'golobo', 13);`
the question is what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What actual values are you using for `$table` and `$key` and `$value`? Plus, tell us the actual errors you're getting; it's important. Are these the actual and constant values `'admin', 'username', 'golobo', 13` being passed?

Comment: If you're trying to pass a value that contains a space, a hyphen, an apostrophe etc. or what could be a [**reserved keyword**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) then that will pose a problem. You would need to wrap your variables in backticks `\``

Comment: Actually I was trying to test those values `useename, golobo, 13` to test the object. @Fred-ii-

Comment: What actual errors are you getting? Plus, are you using error reporting? `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` placed after your opening `<?php` tag.

Comment: I can't help you any further if you're not going to show me what the "so said" error is, good luck with that.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't using the bindings feature of PDO quite right. You should do something like the following:

```
public function update($table, $key, $value, $id) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare(
        "UPDATE $table SET $key = :value WHERE id = :id"
    );
    return $stmt->execute(array(
        ':value' => $value,
        ':id' => $id
    ));
}
```

First, you need to put the entire string to be bound into the key of the binding array. So you put `':id'` rather than `'id'`. Also you were putting the variables directly into the query in the case of `$table` and `$value`, but then attempting to bind them to each other, which doesn't make sense.

Edit: tables and column names can't be bound using PDO.

Comment: fyi: no you cannot bind tables/columns, you can whitelist them though

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work. By the way, what is the best way to do it please? Re: whitlelist. @gandaliter

Comment: I'm not sure why it wouldn't work. You should put quotes around `:value` in the query if it's a string I suppose. What errors are you getting? As for white-listing, I don't know whether PDO has anything like that built in, but you can do it manually by just checking that `$table` and `$key` are in an array of acceptable values.

Comment: *"You should put quotes around :value in the query if it's a string I suppose."* - No. Doing `"UPDATE $table SET $key = ':value' WHERE id = ':id'"` would be invalid, if that's what you meant by that. Quotes like this `':value' => $value,` are ok though, just not in the query itself.

Comment: Oops, my bad again. I guess PDO does that for you.

Comment: Live and learn ;) - Now, in regards to the OP's so-said "errors" that is getting, I asked the OP what they are, but haven't gotten back a response. **Edit**, *got one*. It is important to know what those actual errors are. If we don't know, then there's no way to properly diagnose the problem. See comments under OP's question.